# Export from Excel to txt preserving especial date format

Tags: excel, file, date, text, format

I had been using a code to copy data from excel to .txt removing any unwanted characters, for input to another application:

```
Public DirRoot As String
Public CasNam As String

Public Sub Export()

    Dim intUnit As Integer
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strText As String

    intUnit = FreeFile

    DirRoot = "C:\temp\"
    CasNam = "Test"

        Open DirRoot & CasNam & ".txt" For Output As intUnit

    'End If

    With Worksheets("Export").UsedRange
        For Each rngRow In .Rows
            strText = ""
            For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
                If Len(rngCell.Value) = 0 Then Exit For
                strText = strText & " " & rngCell.Value
            Next
            Print #intUnit, Trim(strText)
        Next
    End With

    Close intUnit

End Sub
```

Now I need to use it under a different set of data where one of the columns is a date with the format: `yyyymmdd`, when I apply the above code, I get that column with the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Is there any way I can preserve the original date format from excel to `.txt`?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
      strText = strText & " " & rngCell.Value
```

To

```
      strText = strText & " " &  Format(rngCell.Value,"yyyymmdd")
```

Good luck

EDIT

Please check this up. `colCounter` is to identify your format requeried column.

```
Dim colCounter as Integer
colCounter = 1
With Worksheets("Export").UsedRange
   For Each rngRow In .Rows
      strText = ""
      colCounter = 1
      For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
        If Len(rngCell.Value) = 0 Then Exit For
        If colCounter = 2  Then ' change 2 to whatever column you want to format
           strText = strText & " " &  Format(rngCell.Value,"yyyymmdd")
        Else
           strText = strText & " " & rngCell.Value
        End if
        colCounter = colCounter + 1
      Next
      Print #intUnit, Trim(strText)
   Next
End With
```

Comment: It works, but now it applies that format (yyyymmdd) to ALL cells, I just need to somehow apply it just for one specific column. I'll try to figure out but probably an IF condition to check column number would work!

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear to me which part declares the variable with the date, but this explanation may be helpful:

```
Sub Date_Convert 

dim dtDate_Orig as date
dim dtDate_Convert as date
dim sDate as String


dtDate_Orig = "22/01/2012"
dtDate_Convert = format(dtDate_Orig, "yyyymmdd")
sDate = Cstr(dtDate_Convert)

'Now you can use the string for a filename 

End Sub
```

Comment: Gents, Thanks for the quick and asserted answers. At the end I added a n IF clause to test where the current cell is located in the column 2 (the one with dates). Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
'~~> Change this to the column which has dates
Col = 2

For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
    If Len(rngCell.Value) = 0 Then Exit For

    If rngCell.Column = Col Then
        strText = strText & " " & Format(rngCell.Value, "yyyymmdd")
    Else
        strText = strText & " " & rngCell.Value
    End If
Next
```